# How to match text and optional repeated identifiers and group them together?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a block of text followed by one or more identifiers (separated by a slash) and having the identifiers be grouped with the block of text using regex in python.

Here is some dummy example data:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 EX 0-02a
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien.
Sed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue
          EX 0-04a

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien, sed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
EX 0-01a / EX 0-05a / EX 0-07a /
EX 0-08a


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing 
elit.
Vestibulum eget 
vestibulum sapien.
                                                      EX 3-11b
```

So far, I have created this regex:

```
(.*?)(\w{2,4} \d-\d{0,2}\w)
```

This successfully captures the text and one singular code, but some blocks have multiple codes (sometimes on multiple lines) and these are not grouped together as the /'s are being picked up as matches.

This is the kind of output I need:

```
[(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.), (EX 0-01a / EX 0-02a / EX 0-05b / EX 0-03a)]
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Wfc4nj/1

Comment: In the data as shown, you don't need regex at all. (1) Break apart the text into paragraphs: can be done either with `text.split('\n\n')` or by iterating line-by-line and using blanks lines to organize the data. (2) In each paragraph, separate the first line (the text) from the rest (the codes you want to capture). (3) Split the lines with codes using `line.split('/')` and remove unwanted whitespace with `strip()`. If the actual data is more complex, you should provide a more fleshed-out example to demonstrate the situation.

Comment: @FMc - as you touched on, the data isn't quite as structured as the example, it contains multiple line breaks throughout the text (this is extracted from a word file) and there is no guarantee of a line break to split up the data line by line. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why example is changed but _This is the kind of output I need:_  isn't changed? And you haven't provided what you had tried in python as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat the pattern matching an identifier in the capture group, and use `\s+` to match 1 or more whitspace chars that also matches a newline if the identifiers can be across multiple lines.

```
\s*(.+?)\s*(\w{2,4} \d-\d{0,2}\w(?:\s+/\s+\w{2,4} \d-\d{0,2}\w)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g3jhi7/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/15D2Dh).

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"\s*(.+?)\s*(\w{2,4} \d-\d{0,2}\w(?:\s+/\s+\w{2,4} \d-\d{0,2}\w)*)"

s = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            " EX 0-02a\n"
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            "Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien.\n"
            "Sed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue\n"
            "          EX 0-04a\n\n"
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            "Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien, sed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue\n"
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n"
            "EX 0-01a / EX 0-05a / EX 0-07a /\n"
            "EX 0-08a\n\n\n"
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n"
            "consectetur adipiscing \n"
            "elit.\n"
            "Vestibulum eget \n"
            "vestibulum sapien.\n"
            "                                                      EX 3-11b")

print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.S))
```

Output

```
[
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'EX 0-02a'),
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nVestibulum eget vestibulum sapien.\nSed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue', 'EX 0-04a'),
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nVestibulum eget vestibulum sapien, sed porta, odio id sollicitudin congue\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'EX 0-01a / EX 0-05a / EX 0-07a /\nEX 0-08a'), 
('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipiscing \nelit.\nVestibulum eget \nvestibulum sapien.', 'EX 3-11b')
]
```

Comment: Nice! This does exactly what I need. Thank you.